# calling a usercontrol from master page

Tags: asp.net

I have a master page and a user control

I have written an event in usercontrol and i want to call that event in my master page.

following are my codes

masterpage ----------- ( I THINK THIS PART IS CORRECT, IT'S  DOING WHAT IT IS SUPPOSE TO DO;CALLING THE USER CONTROL FUNCTION. )

```
Dim App_Cl_tpPerson As New App_Cl_tpPerson

App_Cl_tpPerson.PersonAdd_Click(sender, e)
```

---

usercontrol page ---------- ( I FEEL THE PROBLEM IS HERE )

```
Public Sub PersonAdd_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Try

        If Req_No = 0 Then
            Req_No = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString("reqID"))
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

The error message is  "OBJECT REFERENCE NOT SET TO AN INSTANCE OF AN OBJECT"
.

Comment: which particular line is throwing the exception? step through it with the debugger

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a control in your master page, you need to place an event handler there as well. The reason you are getting the error is because the master page's control is looking for the event handler in the master page's class and there is none defined.

Since all you are doing is getting the QueryString value, which the master page has access to, you can accomplish what you want by simply moving the method from your derived page to your master page.

Then, since you need the Req_No value to be accessible to your templated page, you must add a public property or method to your master page to allow your templated page to access the value.

Finally, to use your property/method call in your templated page, you would do the following:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    Dim Req_No As Integer = CType(Me.Master, MyMasterClassName).Req_NoProperty
End Sub
```

(Note, I don't use VB all that often, so I'm not sure if the CType call would work, but the general idea is you need to cast the Page class' reference to the Master Page to your specific Master Page's class since that is where the property or method you wrote resides).

Comment: Thanks for the information.

I have not placed any control in my master page. All the controls are there in my user control page. By using the above mentioned code I am just referring my user control and calling the required function.

Please help me

Thanks
Nick

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you're trying to reference it from the master page then. Is App_Cl_tpPerson the name of class for your user control page? Maybe I'm not understanding what you mean by User Control page. Do you mean an aspx page that uses the Master template?

Comment: User Control is .ascx file and the name of the UC is App_Cl_tpPerson. What i want is to call the event/function written in  App_Cl_tpPerson.ascx page from my master page. In master page i have declared the user control and could see the event of my UC. The issue is when the UC's event is invoked it says "OBJECT REFERENCE NOT SET TO AN INSTANCE OF AN OBJECT"

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. So one major problem you have is that you're trying to instantiate the user control in your code behind instead of referencing the existing one. You need to register the User Control in your Site.Master file by adding a couple of lines. First, underneath your master declaration: <%@ Register src="App_Cl_tpPerson.ascx" tagname="MyTagName" tagprefix="asp" %>. Then, where you want the control you would do something like: <asp:MyTagName id="App_Cl_tpPerson" runat="server" />. Then your master page should have a reference to your page control.

Comment: This is already done and still the result is the same. Hope I am not troubling you.

Comment: If you've already added the reference in your Master page, then in your codebehind, you need to reference your existing control not create a new instance. To do that, you should remove the line "Dim App_Cl_tpPerson As New App_Cl_tpPerson" because this is trying to instantiate a new control object instead of using the one you have placed in your Site.Master file. Whatever ID you gave the control should have been added to the Site.Master.designer.cs file when you saved it, so you should be able to reference it and call any of its public methods.

Comment: i did excatly what you suggested, i pasted a button on the button click i added App_Cl_tpPerson. and i could not see the function/event in my user control.

Comment: I guess I'm not able to help you further without seeing more of the code. And because I don't have enough reputation here, my options are limited (I can't take this discussion to chat). I don't understand why you would ever need the Master page to fire the user control's event. If you need the user control to pass values back to the Master page, you can do that by Casting the User Control's parent to the Master Page type. Sorry I couldn't help you more. Good luck in finding your answer, I hope someone can help you.

Comment: excatly this is what iam looking for,,, i want user control to pass some values to my master page,, excatly this is the point.can u please pass some code, i think my code is wrong. my idea is to invoke the user controls function or event and the invoked function should return some vale back to master page, excatly this is what you said....and i dont want to add this code in my master page   <uc2:uctrl ID="uctrl1" runat="server" />